# How to create a typed list in Python

Tags: python, list, inheritance, composition, pydantic

I am trying to create a typed list in Python using pydantic. My first idea was to do something like this:

```
class TypedObject(pydantic.BaseModel):
   # some attributes and methods here
   pass 

class TypedList(pydantic.BaseModel):
    items: List[TypedObject]
    
    # some other methods here
```

However, `TypedList` is not really a list but a wrapper around one. What I would actually like is `TypedList` to inherit from something like `List[TypedObject]`, so that I get an actual list but keep the pydantic validation for its elements.

Is this possible (without having to inherit from a naked list and overriding the dunder methods to parse the objects?)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for ["Custom root types"](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types), although that only gets you part way there.

If we define a model like this:

```
import pydantic


class Widget(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str


class WidgetList(pydantic.BaseModel):
    __root__: list[Widget]
```

Then when we initialize an `WidgetList` like this:

```
>>> w = WidgetList(__root__=[Widget(name='foo'), Widget(name='bar')])
```

It serializes like this:

```
>>> w.json()
'[{"name": "foo"}, {"name": "bar"}]'
```

We we can use the `parse_obj` method to create a `WidgetList` from a
list:

```
>>> WidgetList.parse_obj([{"name": "foo"}, {"name": "bar"}])
WidgetList(__root__=[Widget(name='foo'), Widget(name='bar')])
```

Unfortunately, we can't otherwise treat it as a list; we need to
explicitly reference `__root__` when creating it (as seen above) or
when attempting to access list members:

```
>>> w.__root__[0]
Widget(name='foo')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! It seems that this is already an improvement but it is still a wrapper around the list :( I'd love to be able to substitute any list in any place of the code with the typed list. Maybe I should inherit from the collection too and redirect the collection methods to the items variable?

Comment: I guess this is the same amount of work than inheriting directly from list and parsing in the sequence methods. Probably the best is to just add an items method to the above example that just returns the internal list.